# How to capture CTRL+CLICK in a custom Text Editor

Tags: eclipse, text-editor, capture, right-click

I got a custom editor by subclassing TextEditor in Eclipse plugin. I am trying to implement a  **CTRL+CLICK** action(like '**open declaration**' in java editor) in my custom editor. But I cannot figure out how to capture **CTRL+CLICK**. I tried to add a KeyListener to the editor's sourceViewer in its constructor or initialzeEditor(), which didn't work. Has anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

- extension point 'org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors'
- classes org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.AbstractHyperlinkDetector, org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.IHyperlinkDetector and org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.IHyperlink

If you need detailed examples, then take a look at plugin.xml of org.eclipse.jdt.ui. (You can get the source for org.eclipse.jdt.ui either from CVS or from Eclipse Classic SDK install)